# ¿Como se puede actualizar dos datos en una sola consulta en mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

estoy intentando optimizar mi código javascript y me gustaría encontrar la manera de actualizar dos datos en una sola consulta con mongoDB.

Así esta mi esquema.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    id:      { type: String, trim:     true, unique: true },
    balance: { type: Number, required: true  },
    friends: { type: Object, required: false }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  }
);


export default mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Entonces actualmente lo que hago para actualizar los datos es lo siguiente:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate( {id: req.body.id}, {$push: { friends: req.body.friends }} )

await User.findOneAndUpdate( {id: req.body.id}, {$inc: { balance: 5000 }} )
```

Podemos observar que son dos consultas.
Cabe mencionar que el 'id' a actualizar, es el mismo para ambas consultas.
Entonces he intentado hacer algo como esto, para tratar de actualizar los dos datos en una sola consulta.

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate( {id: req.body.id}, {$push: { friends: req.body.friends }}, {$inc: { balance: 5000 }} )
```

Pero no funciona. Lo que hace esta ultima línea es actualizar los amigos, pero no incrementa el saldo, pero a su vez no me arroja ningún error.

¿Alguien sabe si existe la manera de hacer esto? o tengo que usar dos consultas independientes como en el ejemplo? Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mete los 2 en un mismo objeto:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate( {id: req.body.id}, {
   $push: { friends: req.body.friends },
   $inc: { balance: 5000 }
})
```

Aunque se me hace raro una cosa... porque si tu schema dice que friends es un objeto, porque estás intentando hacer un `$push` a el?

Comment: Me funcionó tu código!!! : )